# How to get highlighted text from active terminal in VSCode Extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I am trying to build an extension using the VSCode API in which I need to get user's selected text wherever it is either in the `activeTextEditor` or `activeTerminal`.  I see the way of getting the text from the `selection` for `activeTextEditor`. However, I am not able to find a way to get the highlighted text from `activeTerminal`. Appreciate any help on this.

```
vscode.window.activeTerminal
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no API available for that. You have the `activeTerminal`, but not the content the user selected.

The closer API request I found what this one (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47615), which was in fact connected with the `activeTerminal` API.

So, if you really need this feature, you should open a feature request in VS Code repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) asking for this new API.

Hope this helps